# Saving parts of data from pandas dataframe as individual csv files according to index with hashable first lines

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I wonder if is it possible to save data from one df in parts as many individual csv files?
The part of my input df looks like that:

```
      df_unique_final_1_idx sample  condition
0                         0  P1-12    one_one
1                         0  P1-25    one_one
2                         0  P1-28    one_one
3                         0  P1-22  zero_zero
4                         0  P1-89  zero_zero
5                         0  P1-92  zero_zero
6                         1  P1-12    one_one
7                         1  P1-90    one_one
8                         1  P1-95    one_one
9                         1  P1-26  zero_zero
10                        1  P1-88  zero_zero
11                        1  P1-92  zero_zero
```

I need to prepare individual tab-delimited csv files as the input for further pipeline for every set of samples and conditions with the same `df_unique_final_1_idx` value. In the first hashable line of every csv file should be `df_unique_final_1_idx` value and in the second one - the column header. The desired output of a single csv file for `df_unique_final_1_idx` value = 0 should look like that:

```
#0
#sample  condition
P1-12    one_one
P1-25    one_one
P1-28    one_one
P1-22  zero_zero
P1-89  zero_zero
P1-92  zero_zero
```

Is it possible to do it with any loop? I have hundreds of individual files to prepare so I'll be very grateful for help!

Comment: `for idx, subdf in df.groupby('df_unique_final_1_idx'): subdf.to_csv(f'df_{idx}.csv')`